# How do I find the formula used in excel conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

I am trying to edit an excel template. In one of the formatting Rule, I can only see what appears to be a function 'PercentComplete', saved somewhere. How and where do I see what's inside that function?

[image]

Comment: Maybe inside Formulas > Name Manager ?

Comment: It isn't a function as such (otherwise would be =PercentComplete() ): it is a named range referring to a cell (or cells) somewhere in the Workbook. As @ZygD says, you can look in Name Manager which will show you what PercentComplete refers to. Alternatively, look in the drop-down box at the top-left of the Excel screen (beneath the tool bar, and to the left of the formula bar, which usually just has the address of the cell currently selected) ... this should list all those Names that refer directly to cells.

Comment: Thanks. Name Manager is the place :)